# Regex to ignore Cobol comment line

Tags: regex, cobol

I'd like to use regex to scan a few Cobol files for a specific word but skipping comment lines. Cobol comments have an asterisk on the 7. column. The regex i've gotten so far using a negative lookbehind looks like this:

`^(?<!.{6}\*).+?COPY`

It matches both lines:

```
      *     COPY
            COPY
```

I would assume that .+? overrides the negative lookbehind somehow, but i'm stuck on how to correct this. What would i need to fix to get a regex that only matches the second line?

Comment: Try `^(?!.{6}\*).+?COPY`. BTW, your text in the post contains `*` at Position 8, maybe you need `^(?!.{7}\*).+?COPY` then.

Comment: do you really need negative lookbehind?
`\s{6}\*.*` matches first line but doesn't match second line : https://regex101.com/r/F7C5gX/1

Comment: Fixed the Position of `*`.

Comment: See [`^(?!.{6}\*).+?COPY`](https://regex101.com/r/wX56EK/2), so does it work as expected now?

Comment: Sorry, see https://regex101.com/r/wX56EK/2, where are you using the regex? Tool? Programming language? Show the code.

Comment: Yes, seems lookahead works. Looks like i didn't really understand the difference between lookahead and lookbehind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a lookahead instead of a lookbehind:

```
^(?!.{6}\*).+?COPY
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wX56EK/2).

The lookbehind required some pattern to be absent before the start of the string, and thus was redundant, it always returned *true*. Lookaheads check for a pattern that is *to the right of the current location*.

So,

- `^` - matches the start of the string
- `(?!.{6}\*)` - fails the match if there are any 6 chars followed with `*` from the start of the string (replace `.` with a space if you need to match just spaces)
- `.+?` - matches any 1+ chars, as few as possible, up to the first
- `COPY` -`COPY` substring.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out EVERY comment you could use:

```
^ {6}(?!\*)
```

That will match only lines starting with spaces that DOES NOT have an '*' at the 7th position.

COBOL can use the position 1-6 for numbering the lines, so may be safter to just use:

```
^.{6}(?!\*).*$
```